# Bokeh -- How can I clear my figure/plot before pushing new data to the plot/figure?

Tags: animation, bokeh, timeserieschart

Is there any way to clear a plot/figure in bokeh so that it becomes blank before a new plot is applied? Currently when I try to plot things one after another it will just stack on itself.

Something similar to https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.clear.html

This is what currently happens when I try to 'animate'/update the plotting data: https://gyazo.com/517661dd189ae817f8c619437ab5298d

As you can see the different colored dots stack on top of eachother. So how do I clear the previous set of dots before the current one gets plotted?

I've seen `bokeh.io.reset_output()` But I'm not sure how to use it and whether or not it even is the correct solution in my case.

Here's the code for the dot plotting:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bkplt
import bokeh.io as bkio
import bokeh.palettes as bokpalet
import numpy as np
from math import floor
import time


# This is simply so that the colors change, you can ignore this
pal = bokpalet.viridis(256)
##


#figure/setting up our plotting canvas
f = bkplt.figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=600, title="Column plot")
bkio.output_notebook()
notebookVar = bkio.show(f, notebook_handle=True)
##


for i in range(25):
    # Generating data to plot
    color = pal[floor((256/25)*i)]
    size = np.random.randint(3,15, 25)
    y = np.random.randint(0,100, 25)
    ##


    #Plotting and pushing data to figure
    f.scatter(x, y, size=size, color=color)
    bkio.push_notebook(handle=notebookVar)
    ##


    time.sleep(0.15)
```

Comment: Your code deals with one plot, to which you're applying numerous glyphs (dots). This is why they stack on top of each other. Do you want to create a blank new figure (plot) each time you enter the for loop?

Comment: Yes, but without adding a new figure. If I create a new figure the plot won't update it'll just create a new window with the updated data meaning i'd have to switch screens every 1 second.